# when use click of item it not go to the JQ function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I update a version  of all plugins, PHP, Jquery  in my site
and now this code doesn't work.

when i go to this line :

```
$('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-'+ order_item_id).click();
```

it need go to this line:

```
 $('body').on('click', this.selector, function(e)
```

but it no go there, and I don't have any errors

modalDiscountItem function:

```
$.fn.modalDiscountItem = function (options){
        var settings = $.extend({
            onChargeSuccess: false,
            onChargeFailed: false,
            orderId: 0,
            order_item_id : false,
        }, options);

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        $('body').on('click', this.selector, function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = product_picker.ajax_url + "?action=discount_for_item";
            url += "&order_id=" + settings.orderId;
            url += "&order_item_id=" + settings.order_item_id;
            url += "&TB_iframe=true&width=800&height=700";

            tb_show("Discount for Item ", url);

            icreditChargeModal.success = function(){
                tb_remove();
                deferred.resolve();
            };

            icreditChargeModal.failed = function(){
                tb_remove();
                deferred.fail()
            }
        });

        return deferred;

    }
```

anther function:

```
 order_items_container.on('click', '.create-discount-for-item', function (e) {
        var order_id = $('#post_ID').val();
        var order_item_id = $(this).closest('tr.item').data('order_item_id');

        if (!$('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-' + order_item_id).hasClass('active')) {
            var deferred = $('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-' + order_item_id).modalDiscountItem({
                orderId: order_id,
                order_item_id: order_item_id
            });
            deferred.then(function () {
                location.reload(true);
            }, function () {

            });
        }
        $('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-' + order_item_id).click();
        $('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-' + order_item_id).addClass('active');


    });
```

the output of $('#order_line_items .item .create-discount-for-item-' + order_item_id).length is 1

Comment: What console output do you get from this: `console.log($('#order_line_items .item .create-delivery-from-user-' + order_item_id).length)`?

Comment: it returns **1**